# How to see top 20 e-mails with C#

Tags: c#, pop3

I am trying to do a mail app with Windows Forms C#. I only want to see the top 20 rows of my inbox.

Edit:
The code is working fine but only listing me 20 random emails in my inbox

I've tried this:

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
    client.Authenticate("mail", "passwrd");

    for (int i = client.Count - 20; i < client.Count; i++)
    {
        var message = client.GetMessage(i);
        Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
        txtBoxMails.AppendText("Subject: " + message.Subject + "\n");
    }

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Comment: What's your error/problem?

Comment: code is working fine but as i see it only listing me 20 random mails

Comment: define "top 20". Do you mean most recent by date?

Comment: You may want to rethink if POP3 was the correct selection of Protocol here. POP3 is pretty limited in functionality. The ordering of things is something the server does and your client can't influence this. Normally its the order when mails where received so last incoming mail will be returned first. But we are talking about GMail were POP3 isn't really "native". So GMail might do something less obvious. Think about using IMAP for more control.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [GetMessages](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Pop3_Pop3Client_GetMessages_1.htm). It takes 2 parameters (int startIndex, int count). The index of the first message to get and how many messages.

An example without testing it.

```
var messages = client.GetMessages(0,20);

foreach (var item in messages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use `GetMessageCount` instead of `Count`

```
var messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();
var lastMessageIndex = messageCount-20;
for (int i = messageCount; i > lastMessageIndex; i--)
{
    //Do
}
```